# Trying to create Account on sandbox environment

Tags: apex, rest-api

Account creation does work on production, but I am trying to create tests on the sandbox.

I am using ruby library to do this called [restforce](https://github.com/restforce/restforce). As this error is not restforce related I am posting here, this is what I get :

```
CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: SBQQ.AccountBefore: execution of BeforeInsert

caused by: line 108, column 39: Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.SettingsVO : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.AliasedMetaDataUtils : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.SubscriptionVO : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.QuoteVO : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.QuoteService : Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation:
 Class SBQQ.ConsumptionJunctionUtil : Variable does not exist: ProductConsumptionSchedule
```

I am using version `38.0` of SF api

Got same issue when I use the UI:

[image]

I have googled and look at the salesforce forums but wasn't sure where to even start. Have not had this issue before. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're going to have to follow the chain up and resave your files..

Comment: Your sandbox is broken. It looks like a feature required by CPQ is not present and has resulted in an inconsistent state.

Comment: @DavidReed how do I fix it? I made a copy of production, that's how I created it. Production is working fine

Comment: @EricSSH how do I do that? any links/instructions I can take a look?

Comment: I'd contact CPQ support and/or refresh the sandbox again.